# QT Connect QNetworkReply SIGNAL finished() not firing

Tags: qt, c++11, qt-signals, qt-slot, qt-connection

I had a look at this [link](https://samdutton.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/debugging-signals-and-slots-in-qt/) and except the signal spy and debugging i tried at least everything. I took the example from [this site](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Downloading_Files_QNetworkAccessManager_QNetworkRequest.php). I haven't set up the debugger for now.

My problem is that i want to fire a custom slot and nothing is happening.
I tried qmake and rebuild the project, but the result was the same. 
I am using QTCreator with QT 5.7 msvc2015_64 as kit on a Windows10 machine.
I don't get any unreferenced warnings which should be for the test function (*reply not used). What could be the source of this problem?
Do I have a problem with my finished signal?

From the flow of the program i assume that it is the following:
I create a new pointer to an instance of class `QNetworkAccessManager` named manager.
Then I connect the manager object's signal `finished` to the custom slot `test(QNetworkReply*)` from the object manager.
Now everytime the signal `finished` from object manager is emitted, the function `test` from object manger should be executed.
From the Documentation `QNetworReply *QNetworkAccessManager::get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl))` I assume that when this function is called a new `QNetworkReply*` object is returned and when this object is finished processing the `finished` signal is emited. Do i have to connect my signal and slot in another way?

I tried to declare `QNetworkReply reply* = manager->get....`
and `connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(test()));` but here my application crashes.

When i set up wireshark and filter: http contains "http://www.theuselessweb.com" nothing pops up.

switchwebpanel.h

```
#ifndef SWITCHWEBPANEL_H
#define SWITCHWEBPANEL_H
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QObject>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QDebug>

class switch_panel : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  switch_panel(QObject *parent = 0);
  void doDownload();

signals:

public slots:
  void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
  void test(QNetworkReply * reply);

private:
  QNetworkAccessManager *manager;

};

#endif // SWITCHWEBPANEL_H
```

switchwebpanel.cpp

```
#include <switchwebpanel.h>


switch_panel::switch_panel(QObject *parent):
QObject(parent)
{}


void switch_panel::doDownload(){
  qDebug()<<"Downloader gestartet";
  manager = new QNetworkAccessManager (this);
  qDebug()<<"connect...";

  // Here i want to call the test(QNetworkReply*) function

  connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(test(QNetworkReply*)));
  qDebug()<<"get";
  manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.theuselessweb.com")));
  qDebug()<<"manager gegeted";
}

void switch_panel::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
  qDebug()<<"Async starten";
  if(reply->error()){
    qDebug()<<"error";
    qDebug()<<reply->errorString();
  }
  else {
    qDebug()<<reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader).toString();
    qDebug()<<reply->header(QNetworkRequest::LastModifiedHeader).toDateTime().toString();
    qDebug()<<reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString();
    qDebug()<<"File";
    QFile *file = new QFile("./htmlpanel.txt");
    if(file->open(QFile::Append)){
        file->write(reply->readAll());
        file->flush();
        file->close();
    }
    //delete file;
  }
  reply->deleteLater();
  qDebug()<<"Async fertig";
}
void switch_panel::test(QNetworkReply *reply){
  qDebug()<<"test";
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Download
Downloader gestartet
connect...
get
manager gegeted
```

My Main.cpp calls: `switch_panel panel; panel.doDownload();`

Comment: My Main.cpp calls:   
switch_panel panel;
panel.doDownload();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt's network manager requires an event loop to run, to handle the asynchronous network access. The easiest way is to create a `QCoreApplication` object in your main and call its `exec()` method:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "switchwebpanel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    switch_panel p;
    p.doDownload();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Ok i took your advice and implemented an event loop, but in another way:
reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.theuselessweb.com")));
    qDebug()<<"connect";
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),&loop,SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();

Comment: Qt 5.5 issues a warning that `QEventLoop` cannot be used without a `QApplication` at runtime. It might work, but you should create an instance in main. Nevertheless, you can use a local event loop for your get request.

Comment: Also note that the call to `loop.exec()` will never return! You might want to create a `QEventLoop *` in your `switch_panel` class and call `quit()` when you're finished with the request, to resume execution

Comment: `loop.exec()` does return. When the `finished()` signal is emitted, the connect before the `loop.exec()` will cause the event loop to quit, making it return from exec

Comment: @KevinKrammer You're right, I misread the connect... This is a much more elegant way